# Material design = what should be the position of the + (add new)

Tags: material-design

I couldn't understand  one of the principles of Material design.
On a desktop when I have a left bar list (1/3) and content (2/3) I want to add a + button.
When it should be at the top of the page and when it should float at the bottom right?